# Combining :not() selectors in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select all `tr` elements inside a `table`, except the third and fourth. I managed to do so by using:

```
#table tr:not(:nth-child(3)):not(:nth-child(4))
```

I'd like to combine those selectors because I've some more `:nth-child` entries. Something like this, but it didn't work:

```
#table tr:not(:nth-child(3), :nth-child(4))
```

This *does* work in jQuery, but not in CSS. I'm using Chrome (and I only need it to work there).

I've not been able to find a combining selector for this case. How can I combine selectors with `:not`?

Comment: I've expanded the jQuery aspect of your question into a more general and canonical post now, which you can find here: [What's the difference in the :not() selector between jQuery and CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Selectors level 3 does not allow anything more than a single [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) within a `:not()` pseudo-class. As a jQuery selector, it works because jQuery extends its `:not()` functionality to allow *any selector* (like the `.not()` method).

However, your second syntax is one of the proposed [enhancements to `:not()` in Selectors 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#negation), and works equivalently to your first. Although the example (shown as of this writing anyway) shows a chain of `:not()` selectors, the proposal says:

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a selector list as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

Here a selector list is simply a comma-separated list of selectors.

If you need to negate selectors that contain combinators (`>`, `+`, `~`, space, etc, for example `div p`), you can't use `:not()` in CSS; you'll have to go with the jQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks, the specifications indeed clearly state the differences between CSS3 and CSS4.

Comment: Your note about `:not` not supporting combinators was useful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Although the marked answer is true I just want to point out that you can achieve what you want using css also but just in a different way. Instead of using not you can select those and unapply the stuff you don't want.

```
#table tr {
    /* general case styling */
    color: blue;
}
#table tr:nth-child(3),
#table tr:nth-child(4) {
    color: black;
}
```