# CSS selector for other than the first child and last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am making a very advanced website. My question: Is it possible to select all the other children except for the `:first-child` and the `:last-child`? I know there is a `:not()` selector but it doesn't work with more than one not in the parentheses. This is what I have:

```
#navigation ul li:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
    background: url(images/UISegmentBarButtonmiddle@2x.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: You are mighty brave to use this. Do take note that it will only work on modern browsers, and it will definitely not work on the anti-browser that everyone is using.

Comment: @Radu: "I am making a very advanced website" No surprise there...

Comment: @BoltClock, right, just saying... Word of warning. But anyway, if the target is the iOS Safari as the name of the image suggests, then it should be safe.

Comment: Now I see why this question looks so familiar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403129/combining-not-selectors

Comment: "anti-browser"? Is that the new Google Ultron I keep hearing about?

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Try:

```css
#navigation ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: rofl, the stupidity of me `not()` even trying this before googling :P genius

Comment: That's wrong: `not (A and B)` is not equal to `(not A) and (not B)`, that would rather be `(not A) or (not B)`. It does not work.

Comment: Nope what Salman Abbas said is right. You are thinking of the comma;      

#navigation ul li:not(:first-child), #navigation ul li:not(:last-child)

Answer (score 27):

Sure it will work, you just have to use two 'not' selectors.

```
#navigation ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
```

It will continue down the line after the first one, saying "not the first child" and "not the last child".