# Jsoup how to get specific Text

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I already searched for it but didn't find an answer.
How can I get this Text with Jsoup?

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="content">Don't want to get this Text</div

<div class="content">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</div

<div class="content">WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</div>

<div class="content">Don't want to get this Text</div

</body>
</html>
```

What goes into the question marks?

```
Elements text = document.select("???");
```

Comment: what have you tried ? what did you not find in the tutorial http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax ?

Comment: @njzk2 I already did this tutorial a few days ago. But I think you didn't get what I want to do. I want to get the two divs whith class="content" but not all divs with class="content" ;) And no it's not a duplicate. Mine is a little bit more tricky ;)

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want #content, but not first or last ? see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788018/css-selector-for-other-than-the-first-child-and-last-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all div.content and get the first and second

```
    Elements els = doc.select("div.content");
    System.out.println(els.get(1).text());
    System.out.println(els.get(2).text());
```

or

```
    Elements els = doc.select("div.content:eq(1)");
    System.out.println(els.first().text());
    els = doc.select("div.content:eq(2)");
    System.out.println(els.first().text());
```

Comment: Thank you
Is it possible to make two Jsoup Connections in one doInBackground() ?

Comment: sorry; i don't get the question

Comment: No no you understand the question right. it's another question :D can i do two jsoup connections in on doInBackground() method?