# css comma separated selectors do not work for form input:not(...)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**CSS**:

```
form input:not([type='button']),form input:not([type='submit']) { width: 200px }
```

**HTML**:

```html
<form>
  <input type='button' value='button' />
  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
  <input type='text' value='text' />
</form>
```

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/imibew/edit#javascript,html,live

**Issue**: all input elements are getting width of 200px, where I just want the input of type text to have 200px.

**Quirk**: if you just list one selector in the , and not have a comma separated list, it works correctly.

**Question**: can I use commas when using :not()'s in CSS?  Using lists in the selector seems to break it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comma represents a logical OR in selector syntax. Each element will thus be matched against each part of your selector at a time, and if it satisfies at least one of those parts, the rule is applied.

So in your case, this is what happens:

1. The `input[type='button']` will match your `form input:not([type='submit'])` selector
2. The `input[type='submit']` will match your `form input:not([type='button'])` selector
3. The `input[type='text']` will (obviously) match *both* selectors

That's why your rule gets applied to *all* your form inputs.

If you want to combine both negations, chain them like so, instead of using a comma-separated list:

```
form input:not([type='button']):not([type='submit']) { width: 200px }
```

Comment: As I mention in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7403148/106224), you won't be able to use commas with the `:not()` pseudo-class in level 3. However, it is slated to be enhanced to allow a comma-separated list of compound selectors in [level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation), so theoretically it would look like `form input:not([type='button'], [type='submit'])`.