# Unable to do `:not(.foo .bar)`

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why can't I do `div:not(.wrapper2 .exception)`? Ie. all divs except `.wrapper2 .exception`.

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/4swjmhtr/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="exception">
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="exception">
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:not(.wrapper2 .exception) {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Is the one you want to except the `.wrapper2 .exception`, or `.wrapper2` and `.exception`?

Comment: Hi! All divs except `.wrapper2 .exception` yeah. Thanks. Updated question.

Comment: This explains the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403129/combining-not-selectors-in-css/7403148#7403148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't combine `not()` selectors like this, only one selector at a time can go in.

To select all divs except `.exception` inside `.wrapper2`:

```
div:not(.wrapper2) div:not(.exception)
```

Comment: How do you know the OP didn't intend for it to only apply to the last `div`, which is `.wrapper2 .exception`.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question. Updated my answer

Comment: Note that this will only work if there are exactly two levels of divs - any more and it will not work correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants

Comment: It seems BoltClock and Fabrizio Calderan are right. I think the answer below by Marc is better in retrospect.

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting all the child div's except for the last one, this is what is needed.

```css
div > div {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
div.wrapper2 > div.exception {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="exception">
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="exception">
        <p>Hi - not this one!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```