# Table Alternating Color nth-child:not(.class)

Tags: html, css, alternating

I have multiple `<tr>` in a table and some of those are followed by a `<tr class="colapsed">` which has some details. Not all the `<tr>` tags have details.
I need to create alternating colors but ignoring the collapsed class. I've tried to use `table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) { background:red }` but it doesn't seem to work as I want.

Any ideas?

```css
table>tbody>tr:not(.collapsed):nth-child(odd) {
  background: red
}
.collapsed {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table class="rwd-table table-auto doubletr">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td>
        <div>2016-10-02</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2016-02-03</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Pagamento por Multibanco</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>90</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2895.01</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="expand-wrap">
          <a class="expand" href="#"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsed">
      <td colspan="7">
        details here
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>2016-10-02</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2016-02-03</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Pagamento por Multibanco</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>90</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2895.01</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="expand-wrap">
          <a class="expand" href="#"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsed">
      <td colspan="7">
        details here
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>2016-10-02</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2016-02-03</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Pagamento por Multibanco</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>90</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2895.01</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="expand-wrap">
          <a class="expand" href="#"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>2016-10-02</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2016-02-03</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Pagamento por Multibanco</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>90</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>2895.01</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="expand-wrap">
          <a class="expand" href="#"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403129) doesn't describe my situation. I'm trying to prevent the odd event from considering all the tags with collapsed class.

**Alternative Resolution**
For those in the same situation. 
Since `:nth-` selectors don't care about visibility I solved my issue using a simple jquery function.

```js
var n = 1;
$("table>tbody>tr:not('[class*=collapsed]')").each(function() {
  if (n % 2) { //even
    $(this).css("background", "red");
  } else { //odd
    $(this).css("background", "yellow");
  }
  n += 1;
})
```

Comment: if you're open to implementing bootstrap for your project then you can try its table classes and it will get this dont easily for you along with making it responsive..check the documentation at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible given that `:nth-` selectors don't care about visibility. You can `:not` out of the ones you don't want, but the `:nth` isn't going to skip it in its algorithm. Maybe this will help?

http://nthmaster.com/

Comment: This is a useful answer. Thank you very much!